# UITableview load cell longtime Swift - Need advise tuning

Tags: uitableview, swift, asynchronous

Please kindly refer code in attach and refer in the image as well. I need your advise how can I make quicker for loading

http://imageshack.com/a/img901/7079/mOQkum.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img909/2775/E2zTKs.png

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let wishRow = self.wishDataList.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! NSMutableArray
    println(userImageList.count)
    switch (wishRow).count{

    case 4:

        let cell:WishHeaderTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! WishHeaderTableViewCell
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            cell.LblCity.text = wishRow[1] as? String
            cell.ImgAddWish.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            cell.ImgAddWish.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.ImgAddWish.autoresizesSubviews = false
            //           cell.ImageViewTripOwner.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            //           cell.ImageViewTripOwner.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.ImageViewTripOwner.autoresizesSubviews = false
            for object in self.userImageList{
                if object[0] as? String == (wishRow[3] as? PFUser)?.objectId{

                    cell.ImageViewTripOwner.image = UIImage(data: (object[1] as! PFFile).getData()!)

                    //SharedFunction.imageResize(UIImage(data: (object[1] as PFFile).getData())!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
                }
            }
        })

        return cell

    default:

        let cell:WishItemTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellItem", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! WishItemTableViewCell
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            cell.LblItemName.text = wishRow[5] as? String
            cell.ImgItem.image = wishRow[7] as? UIImage
            //UIImage(data: (wishRow[7] as PFFile).getData())
            //SharedFunction.imageResize(UIImage(data: (wishRow[7] as PFFile).getData())!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
            cell.ImgRequestorItem.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.ImgRequestorItem.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.ImgRequestorItem.autoresizesSubviews = false
            cell.ImgRequestorItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            for object in self.userImageList{
                if object[0] as? String == wishRow[8] as? String{
                    let realImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 1.5, y: 1.5, width: 17, height: 17))
                    realImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.5
                    realImage.clipsToBounds = true
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        realImage.image = UIImage(data: (object[1] as! PFFile).getData()!)
                    })
                    //SharedFunction.imageResize(UIImage(data: (object[1] as PFFile).getData())!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 17, height: 17))
                    cell.ImgRequestorItem.addSubview(realImage)
                }
            }
            cell.ImgBackgroundTick.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
            cell.ImgBackgroundTick.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.ImgBackgroundTick.autoresizesSubviews = false
            cell.ImgBackgroundTick.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            let realImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 1.5, y: 1.5, width: 12, height: 12))
            realImage.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            realImage.clipsToBounds = true
            realImage.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.450, green: 0.419, blue: 0.321 , alpha: 1)
            realImage.image = UIImage(named: "ic_tick")
            cell.ImgBackgroundTick.addSubview(realImage)
        })
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, why are you using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in` in cell creation? You don't have to. Remove this method so the code should look like the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
let wishRow = self.wishDataList.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! NSMutableArray
println(userImageList.count)
switch (wishRow).count{

case 4:

    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! WishHeaderTableViewCell
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        cell.LblCity.text = wishRow[1] as? String
        cell.ImgAddWish.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.ImgAddWish.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.ImgAddWish.autoresizesSubviews = false
        //           cell.ImageViewTripOwner.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        //           cell.ImageViewTripOwner.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.ImageViewTripOwner.autoresizesSubviews = false
        for object in self.userImageList{
            if object[0] as? String == (wishRow[3] as? PFUser)?.objectId{

                cell.ImageViewTripOwner.image = UIImage(data: (object[1] as! PFFile).getData()!)

                //SharedFunction.imageResize(UIImage(data: (object[1] as PFFile).getData())!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
            }
        }

    return cell

default:

    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellItem", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! WishItemTableViewCell
        cell.LblItemName.text = wishRow[5] as? String
        cell.ImgItem.image = wishRow[7] as? UIImage
        //UIImage(data: (wishRow[7] as PFFile).getData())
        //SharedFunction.imageResize(UIImage(data: (wishRow[7] as PFFile).getData())!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        cell.ImgRequestorItem.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.ImgRequestorItem.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.ImgRequestorItem.autoresizesSubviews = false
        cell.ImgRequestorItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        for object in self.userImageList{
            if object[0] as? String == wishRow[8] as? String{
                let realImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 1.5, y: 1.5, width: 17, height: 17))
                realImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.5
                realImage.clipsToBounds = true
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    realImage.image = UIImage(data: (object[1] as! PFFile).getData()!)
                })
                //SharedFunction.imageResize(UIImage(data: (object[1] as PFFile).getData())!, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 17, height: 17))
                cell.ImgRequestorItem.addSubview(realImage)
            }
        }
        cell.ImgBackgroundTick.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
        cell.ImgBackgroundTick.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.ImgBackgroundTick.autoresizesSubviews = false
        cell.ImgBackgroundTick.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let realImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 1.5, y: 1.5, width: 12, height: 12))
        realImage.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        realImage.clipsToBounds = true
        realImage.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.450, green: 0.419, blue: 0.321 , alpha: 1)
        realImage.image = UIImage(named: "ic_tick")
        cell.ImgBackgroundTick.addSubview(realImage)
    return cell
}}
```